# Facebook sharer debugger says image corrupt or invalid format

Tags: facebook, debugging, share

Out of the blue anytime I attempt to share an article to Facebook from my website the image is not provided. I check Facebook debugger and it says Provided

> og:image URL, MY URL HERE could not be processed as an image. It may
>   be corrupted or may have an invalid format

. This is for every single article. If i mash the rescrape button a couple of times the image will pull in. My images are in an amazon S3 bucket. All my Open Graph meta data is the same as it was when was working fine. I have og:image, url, secure url, height, width, and all other needed meta. I am not sure why it has stopped working all the sudden.

Comment: Anyone? The image is declared and debugger shows it has correct image URL but it does not matter which article I share it says the image is corrupt or invalid.

Comment: Yep.  I got the same problem.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't on perfectly valid images.

Comment: I have taken a jpg that doesn't work and converted it to png, and that image then worked.  However, I have other pngs that don't work.  It doesn't seem to be related to image size or type from my findings.